# Why do I need to "git add" my checked out file?

Tags: git, version-control

I check out a project with `git clone`, added some files, and edited the `README.md` that had been check out.

When I do a `git commit`, I get this advice to add the file that I've checked out.

```
# Changes not staged for commit:
#   (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
#   (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
#
#       modified:   README.md
```

- Why is this file not staged?
- What can I do to so that this file will be automatically staged?

Comment: As others have noted, you must stage the file.  `git checkout` does not "check the file out" like you may be familiar with in a checkout/edit/checkin version control system.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Git doesn't add the changed files and new files to the commit. First you need to change the files to the index stage (changes to be commited). You can do this with `git add file` for new and modified files or `git rm` for removed files. Only the files that are listed in "changes to be commited" when you use `git status` will be commited when you perform a `git commit`.

One simple way to add changed files automatically when you perform a `git commit` is to pass the option `-a`: `git commit -a`. This way, all changed files will be commited. However, new files and removed files will be not commited. If you want to commit only some changed files, you need to add each one manually with `git add`.

Answer (score 3):

The file is not staged because changes are not staged by default. If you don't want to use the git index functionality, you need to commit changes by running `git commit -a` or `git commit file1 file2...`.

Answer (score 0):

Try doing this:  `git commit -a -m "message"`

To add all changes  `git add .`

Comment: You shouldn't regularly use `.` as that will go through the whole working directory and add everything it finds; build products, scratch files, temporary test data, etc. The `-a` flag is much better, as it adds only changes to files that have already been marked as belonging in the repository.